# I want to change value in object after specific time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need to set status of subscription plan to active and schedule it after 30 days to be something else 
How to do that in NodeJS 
other case I want to make charge in hold status after adding it 
and after 14 days it will not be hold 
so how to schedule tasks in node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use node cron [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

you can check using https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_0 this site

Comment: I want to schedule the task one time after 14 days